# Remove leading space in ListTile flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using ListTile, I have used `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero` but still there is gap before the icon. I have tried using alignments in Column but still I have faced this problem with ListTile. It worked with the container.

How can we remove the leading space. It looks like some invisible border or something else. Please help me resolve this thing.

Full code and Image attached,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: CustomExpansionPanelList(),
  ));
}

class CustomExpansionPanelList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomExpansionPanelListState createState() =>
      _CustomExpansionPanelListState();
}

class _CustomExpansionPanelListState extends State<CustomExpansionPanelList> {
  List<Item> _data = generateItems(3);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Custom Expansion Panel List'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: _data.map<Widget>((Item item) {
              return Column(
                children: [
                  CustomExpansionTile(
                    title: item.headerValue,
                    children: [
                      CustomExpansionTile(
                        title: 'Child Title',
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text('Child Content 1'),
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            title: Text('Child Content 2'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(item.expandedValue),
                        subtitle: Text(
                            'Additional content for ${item.headerValue}'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  Item({
    required this.expandedValue,
    required this.headerValue,
  });

  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
}

List<Item> generateItems(int numberOfItems) {
  return List<Item>.generate(numberOfItems, (int index) {
    return Item(
      headerValue: 'Panel $index',
      expandedValue: 'This is item number $index',
    );
  });
}

class CustomExpansionTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final List<Widget> children;

  CustomExpansionTile({
    required this.title,
    required this.children,
  });

  @override
  _CustomExpansionTileState createState() => _CustomExpansionTileState();
}

class _CustomExpansionTileState extends State<CustomExpansionTile> {
  bool _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0), // Remove default padding
          leading: Icon(
            _isExpanded
                ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_up
                : Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
            color: Colors.blue, // Customize the arrow color
          ),
          title: Text(widget.title),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
            });
          },
        ),
        if (_isExpanded)
          ...widget.children,
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IconData has its own padding which can't be removed, You can check it by replacing Icon with Text that it is staring from left.

You can shift icon paint a little left with Transform.

```dart
ListTile(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0), // Remove default padding
  leading: Transform.translate(
    offset: Offset(-5, 0),// your value
    child: Icon(
```